# Python csv list index out of range

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write from json to csv, so each value(pH) is in different row, but I keep getting

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Meslosana/getValues.py", line 22, in 
> lines[i][1] = pH
> IndexError: list index out of range

I will also add different values in the same rows but different columns.

My csv file looks like this, it does not have empty lines.

```
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0
```

and each time I run my code it creates empty line at the bottom.

Here is my code

```
import json
import csv

file = 'LaukiGeojson/Zemdegas.geojson'
cord = []
with open(file) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
i = 1
for feature in data['features']:
    cord = feature['geometry']['coordinates'][0]
    pH = feature['properties']['pH']
    print(pH)
    print(feature)
    print(data)
    # saglabaa
    r = csv.reader(open('LaukiAnalizes/Zemdegas.csv'))
    lines = list(r)

    print(len(lines))
    #lines[i][0] = 1
    lines[i][1] = pH
    #lines[i][2] = 1
    #lines[i][3] = 1
    #lines[i][4] = 1
    i += 1

    writer = csv.writer(open('LaukiAnalizes/Zemdegas.csv', 'w', newline=''))
    writer.writerows(lines)


# saglabaa
r = csv.reader(open('LaukiAnalizes/Zemdegas.csv'))
lines = list(r)
lines[0][0] = 'ID'
lines[0][1] = 'pH'
lines[0][2] = 'P'
lines[0][3] = 'K'
lines[0][4] = 'Mg'


writer = csv.writer(open('LaukiAnalizes/Zemdegas.csv', 'w', newline=''))
writer.writerows(lines)
open('LaukiAnalizes/Zemdegas.csv').close()
```

Comment: could you add the full traceback for the error?

Comment: What makes you so sure that `lines[i]` even exists?

Comment: variable i should be from 1-9 and my csv file has 9 lines

Comment: you start with an i of 1 .... and increment it once per line .... in python we count from 0 to len()-1  - so if you got 9 lines you have a list from index 0 to 8. not 9.

Comment: but i get error even if i is 1 or 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid code that blindly assumes that a CSV file has a given number of lines. This is better:

Check if the current line even exists in the CSV, if it does update the `pH` value in-place, otherwise append a new line.

```
import json
import csv

GEOJSON_FILE = 'LaukiGeojson/Zemdegas.geojson'
CSV_FILE = 'LaukiAnalizes/Zemdegas.csv'

with open(GEOJSON_FILE, encoding='utf8') as f:
    geo_data = json.load(f)

with open(CSV_FILE, encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    lines = list(reader)

for i, feature in enumerate(geo_data['features']):
    pH = feature['properties']['pH']
    if i < len(lines):
        lines[i][1] = pH
    else:
        lines.append([1, pH, 1, 1, 1])

with open(CSV_FILE, 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(lines)
```

The number of times you are opening and closing the CSV file seemed rather confusing to me. Read it once, write it once. Also, use a context manager (`with open(...) as ...)` for all your file interactions.

Answer (score 0):

Python is 0-indexed. This means the index of the first line is 0, and the index of the final element is length-1. This is where you get the error, as when your i=9, this will be attempting to access a row that doesn't exist. Fix this by setting `i=0` at the start instead of `i=1`.

Comment: I still get the error, I tried printing out i and it stopped at 2